# Is the VS2017 8.1SDK different that the standalone installer?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, sdk, visual-studio-2017

All of our developer machines have a copy of:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\**MSCOREE.lib**`

After rebuilding a machine and installing *Windows 8.1 SDK and UCRT SDK* using *Visual Studio 2017*'s installer, I was expecting to find `MSCOREE.lib` in the same location... but it's not there.

Is the *Visual Studio 2017* version of *Windows 8.1 SDK* different than the standalone *Windows 8.1 SDK* installer?

## Additional Context

For reference, I currently have `MSCOREE.lib` installed in the following locations:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Lib\um\x64`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7\Lib\um\x64`

Comment: I ran into the same problem. After installing the Windows SDK 10.x, I was expecting a similar location as Windows SDK 7.1 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\mscoree.lib. Unfortunately not.